# Overriding style with css

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to change the position of a side panel that comes up when an option is being hovered over.  Here is the code from chrome developer tools: [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7suVP.png).  I just need to change that style = "left : 80px" to 76px. The developer tools just have this attribute saved under element.style which I can't really target in my css file.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can use `!important`, though it would be best to use JavaScript to override it. It may pay to look into [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). Another great article on it can be found [here](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).

Comment: So I looked at all of those websites and tried to specifically target it, this is the code I came up with :  nav#side_nav, ul.sidebar-bg-color ps-ready ps-container, li.nav_trigger nav_open, div.sub_panel{
   left : 76px;
},  But it seems to be targeting the sidebar rather than the sub panel.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have a look at the guide lines around asking a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It's difficult to assist if you code is an image, much better to create a code snippet to help other reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have a look at the guide lines around asking a good question stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It's difficult to assist if you code is an image, much better to create a code snippet to help other reproduce the problem.